# Bind return type to supertype via Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

Is there any possiblity to bind my type of the field that I am trying to expose with the @Getter annotation to a supertype?

For example I have the following code:

```
@AppScope
public final class ProtrocolMessageRepository {

    @Getter
    private final Subject<StartGameResponse> startGameSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    private final Subject<WaitForGameResponse> waitForGameSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    private final Subject<FinishedGameResponse> finishedGameSubject = PublishSubject.create();
}
```

I am trying to expose the `startGameSubject` field as an `Observable` rather than a `Subject`. `Observable` is a supertype of `Subject`.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible on a direct way. But you can do something like this:

```
public final class ProtrocolMessageRepository {
    private final Subject<StartGameResponse> startGameSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    @Getter
    private final Observable<StartGameResponse> startGameObservable = startGameSubject;
}
```

However, I doubt that this is really worth it, because the code clearly is less comprehendable, but not that much shorter than writing your own manual getter without Lombok. So you really should implement that manually.